# AWS-CDK - DynamoDB Initial Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Using the AWS CDK for a Serverless project but I've hit a sticking point. My project deploys a DynamoDB table which I need to populate with data prior to my Lambda function executing.

The data that needs to be loaded is generated by making API calls and isn't static data that can be loaded by a .json file or something simple.

Any ideas on how to approach this requirement for a production workload?

Comment: Add a [WaitCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudformation.CfnWaitConditionHandle.html) and make it depends on successful deployment of the other resource. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry I'm missing something, how does the use of a WaitCondition execute code to load data into DynamoDB?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) may be another option.

Comment: Thanks, the CustomResource appears to be exactly what I’ve been looking for. If you’d like to make that an answer I’m happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_custom-resources.AwsCustomResource.html) in order to make a `PutItem` call to the table.

```java
AwsSdkCall initializeData = AwsSdkCall.builder()
        .service("DynamoDB")
        .action("putItem")
        .physicalResourceId(PhysicalResourceId.of(tableName + "_initialization"))
        .parameters(Map.ofEntries(
                Map.entry("TableName", tableName),
                Map.entry("Item", Map.ofEntries(
                        Map.entry("id", Map.of("S", "0")),
                        Map.entry("data", Map.of("S", data))
                )),
                Map.entry("ConditionExpression", "attribute_not_exists(id)")
        ))
        .build();

AwsCustomResource tableInitializationResource = AwsCustomResource.Builder.create(this, "TableInitializationResource")
        .policy(AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements(List.of(
                PolicyStatement.Builder.create()
                        .effect(Effect.ALLOW)
                        .actions(List.of("dynamodb:PutItem"))
                        .resources(List.of(table.getTableArn()))
                        .build()
        )))
        .onCreate(initializeData)
        .onUpdate(initializeData)
        .build();
tableInitializationResource.getNode().addDependency(table);
```

The `PutItem` operation will be triggered if the stack is created or if `table` is updated (`tableName` is supposed to be different in that case). If it doesn't work for some reason, you can set `physicalResourceId` to random value, i.e. UUID, to trigger the operation for each stack update (the operation is idempotent due to `ConditionExpression`)

Answer (score 2):

[CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) allows you to write custom provisioning logic. In this case you could use something like a AWS Lambda Function in a Custom Resource to read in the custom json and update DynamoDb.