# How to create a dynamo db table and create item entries in the same dynamo db table using cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a dynamo db table using cloud formation template and then i want to create entries in that table using the same cloud formation template in a single stack. Can someone tell how this can be achieved , it is possible or not ?

I tried using the custom resources lambda function but it does not work

Comment: *"I tried using the custom resources lambda function but it does not work"* - why not? Custom resource do "work" and are the way to go (unfortunately). And you should really not use bare CF anymore, at least use CDK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724486/aws-cdk-dynamodb-initial-data

Comment: There is not official guidance not to use CloudFormation! Why would you suggest someone use CDK over CFN?

Comment: @LeeHannigan  Because CF is bad enough, at least CDK makes it somewhat useable. No need for "official guidance" here.

Comment: "And you should really not use bare CF anymore".

This sounds like using CFN is bad, but its only personal opinion. "I personally prefer to use CDK as I feel its more usable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example that creates a table and adds 5 items:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  MyDynamoDBTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    Properties:
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: pk
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: sk
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: pk
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: sk
          KeyType: RANGE
  MyCustomResourceLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          tableName: !Ref MyDynamoDBTable
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
          const client = new AWS.DynamoDB();
          const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
          const response = require('cfn-response');
          
          exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
            try {
              const tableName = process.env.tableName
              console.log(tableName)
              var params = {
                'TableName': tableName
              };
            
              client.waitFor('tableExists', params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else     console.log(data);           // successful response
              });

              const itemsToAdd = [
                { pk: 'item1', sk: 'sortKey1', otherAttribute: 'value1' },
                { pk: 'item2', sk: 'sortKey2', otherAttribute: 'value2' },
                { pk: 'item3', sk: 'sortKey3', otherAttribute: 'value3' },
                { pk: 'item4', sk: 'sortKey4', otherAttribute: 'value4' },
                { pk: 'item5', sk: 'sortKey5', otherAttribute: 'value5' },
              ];
              
              const putItemPromises = itemsToAdd.map((item) => {
                const params = {
                  TableName: tableName,
                  Item: item,
                };
                return dynamodb.put(params).promise();
              });
              
              await Promise.all(putItemPromises).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
              
              const responseData = { Result: 'Items added successfully' };
              await response.send(event, context, response.SUCCESS, responseData);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
              const responseData = { Error: 'Something went wrong' };
              await response.send(event, context, response.FAILED, responseData);
            }
          };
      Timeout: 30
  MyLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole'
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess'
  MyCustomResource:
    Type: 'Custom::MyCustomResource'
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt MyCustomResourceLambdaFunction.Arn
```

Full article [here](https://repost.aws/articles/ARanFOzKSzSj2c27o0-SvxnQ)

Comment: Hello Lee, It works but actually after stack creation , during creation of MyCustomResource it was taking so much of time and then create for custom resource failed with the reason "CloudFormation did not receive a response from your Custom Resource" and then due to rollback everything got deleted. Could you please suggest something and help me to resolve this issue as well ?

Comment: Thanks, there was an await missing in the script for `response.send()`

Answer (score -1):

You can drop a csv file containing your records in an existing bucket.

```
id,name
1,A
2,B
3,C
```

Then import this file while creating the table.

```
  Table:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      TableName: Sample
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: name
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema: 
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: name
          KeyType: RANGE
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
      ImportSourceSpecification:
        InputCompressionType: NONE
        InputFormat: CSV
        S3BucketSource: 
          S3Bucket: mybucket-1234567890
          S3KeyPrefix: myfile
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-table-importsourcespecification.html